# How to count permutations with cycles of length at least 51 in $S_{100}$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let consider permutation $ \in S_{100} $ How to count the number of permutations of those which contains a cycle of length 51 at least. ( so I would like a cycle of length 52,53,54,....,100)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the easiest way or the type of answer you are looking for but one thing to notice is that since 51>100/2=50, we know that any permutation with a cycle of length 51, the only other cycles it can contain are less than 50. So for example if $c(51)$ is the number of cycles with length 51 and $p(49)$ are the number of permutations on $49$ elements then the number of of permutations in $S_{100}$ with length $51$ cycles is $c(51)p(49)$ since there is no double counting due to the fact a permutation on $49$ elements can not contain a permutation of length $51$.

Answer (score 2):

The species  of decompositions of  permutations into cycles  marked by
the number of cycles is
$$\mathfrak{P}(\mathcal{U}\mathfrak{C}(\mathcal{Z})).$$
This gives the generating function
$$G(z, u) = \exp\left(u\left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)\right)$$
which immediately yields
$$\left[n\atop k\right] =
n! [z^n] \frac{1}{k!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^k.$$

We now ask about the problem of counting permutations of $2n$ elements
with a cycle of length more than $n.$

This gives the marked species
$$\mathfrak{P}\left(\sum_{q=1}^n \mathfrak{C}_{=q}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{U} \sum_{q\ge n+1} \mathfrak{C}_{=q}(\mathcal{Z})\right).$$

The corresponding generating function is
$$G(z, u)
=\exp\left(\sum_{q=1}^n \frac{z^q}{q}
+ u \sum_{q\ge n+1} \frac{z^q}{q}\right).$$

We seek $$(2n)! [z^{2n}] [u^1] G(z, u).$$
Extracting the coefficient in $u$ first we get
$$[u^1] G(z, u)
= [u^1] \exp\left(\sum_{q=1}^n \frac{z^q}{q}\right)
\times \exp\left(u \sum_{q\ge n+1} \frac{z^q}{q}\right)
\\ = \exp\left(\sum_{q=1}^n \frac{z^q}{q}\right)
[u^1] \exp\left(u \sum_{q\ge n+1} \frac{z^q}{q}\right)
\\ = \exp\left(\sum_{q=1}^n \frac{z^q}{q}\right)
\sum_{q\ge n+1} \frac{z^q}{q}.$$

Extracting coefficients from this we get
$$(2n)! \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}
[z^p] \exp\left(\sum_{q=1}^n \frac{z^q}{q}\right)
[z^{2n-p}] \sum_{q\ge n+1} \frac{z^q}{q}.$$

which is
$$(2n)! \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2n-p}
[z^p] \exp\left(\sum_{q=1}^n \frac{z^q}{q}\right).$$

We have $p\lt n$ however so we may extend the inner sum to
infinity to get
$$(2n)! \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2n-p}
[z^p] \exp\left(\sum_{q=1}^\infty \frac{z^q}{q}\right)
\\ = (2n)! \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2n-p}
[z^p] \exp\log\frac{1}{1-z}
\\ = (2n)! \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2n-p}
[z^p] \frac{1}{1-z}
= (2n)! \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2n-p}.$$

For a final answer of
$$(2n)! (H_{2n}-H_n)
\sim \log 2 \times (2n)!.$$

This yields the sequence
$$1, 14, 444, 25584, 2342880, 312888960, 57424792320, 
\\ 13869128448000, 4264876094976000, 1627055289796608000,
\\ 754132445894209536000, 417405110861381271552000,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A201546](https://oeis.org/A201546), 
where additional material awaits.

**Remark.**  The generating  function $[u^1]  G(z, u)$  could  also be
derived from the species
$$\mathfrak{P}(\mathfrak{C}_{\le n}(\mathcal{Z}))
\times \mathfrak{C}_{\ge n+1}(\mathcal{Z}).$$

Answer (score 2):

For each $k>50$, we claim there are $100!/k$ permutations with a $k$-cycle.  To see this, write down the numbers from $1$ to $100$ in arbitrary order; declare the first $k$ to be a cycle, and interpret the remaining $100-k$ symbols as a permutation.  As there are $k$ rotations of the cycle, the claim follows.  Summing from $k=51$ to $100$, the final sum is
$$100!\ (H_{100}-H_{51})$$
which agrees with Marko Riedel's answer.

Comment: @WillOrrick Thanks for catching it - have to read those questions carefully!